# Using ASP.NET MVC 4 and Web API components within a .NET f/w 4.0 and VS2010-constructed app

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

I'm a little confused about one thing with version levels of various .NET software components related to ASP.NET MVC and the web api.  Now I know VS2012 and .NET f/w 4.5 are going RTM "real soon now", but I don't want to make that up-transition for awhile (as in 6 months or longer).  I am coding a new app right now whose initial incarnation (dictated by consulting client) has to be .NET f/w 4.0 and utilizing VS2010 (yes I know you can target downwards with VS2012 but that is not an option for me in this case - as a consultant you are sometimes dictated the tools/versions etc that you MUST use for a contract).  So finally to the crux of my question - I just came across an article on MSDN by Mike Wasson, written in Jan/Feb 2012 timeframe, and it looks as if he used VS2010 and .NET f/w 4.0, but demonstrating the new-ish Web API technology utilizing ASP.NET MVC 4.  So it IS possible to install the ASP.NET MVC 4 component within the context of .NET f/w 4.0 and VS2010, AND utilize the Web API component?  Which, if that is true, I might want to do with this particular project rather than just using ASP.NET MVC 3 (and without using the Web API stuff at all), which is what i thought I would need to do.  It's just that I thought to use ASP.NET MVC 4 and/or the Web API stuff, one HAD to use .NET f/w 4.5 RC and VS2012 RC prior to Sep 12 (or their RTMs after Sep 12).  Is that not correct?

Answer (score 0):

You can use mvc 4 and web api with .net 4.0. You cannot use features of .net 4.5 in it but all other will work.

Comment: Thanks Kirill.  So, hmmm... there are some features/classes etc. that might not work within .NET f/w 4.0 - I suppose it's too much to hope for that there is a summary of what those are somewhere; plus, seeing as how Mike Wasson did that whole article using ASP.NET MVC 4 and the Web API stuff within a .NET 4.0 context, it seems as if it would be a good assumption that the stuff that works within .NET f/w 4.5 but not within .NET f/w 4.0, is fairly minimal and/or not the most important stuff?

Answer (score 0):

> So it IS possible to install the ASP.NET MVC 4 component within the
>   context of .NET f/w 4.0 and VS2010

Of course. It's RC at the time of this writing but you could download and install it from here: http://www.asp.net/mvc/mvc4 (Download the standalone installer executable for VS2010 from here: http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=29935)

Even when it hits RTM you will be able to use it with VS2010. Of course you won't be able to use .NET 4.5 speicic features with VS2010 though (things like `async`/`await`).